# MUI: GridErrorHandler - An unexpected error occurred. Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem on my grid table, I received this error

> MUI: GridErrorHandler - An unexpected error occurred. Error: Maximum
> call stack size exceeded.  RangeError: Maximum call stack size
> exceeded

```
{
  field: 'status', headerName: 'Action', sortable: true, flex: 1, renderCell: (params) => {
    let status;
    const onClick = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation(); // don't select this row after clicking

      const api: GridApi = params.api;
      const thisRow: Record<string, GridCellValue> = {};

      api
        .getAllColumns()
        .filter((c) => c.field !== '__check__' && !!c)
        .forEach(
          (c) => (thisRow[c.field] = params.getValue(params.id, c.field)),

        );

      handleReviewApplication({ ARN: thisRow.ARN, id: thisRow.id })
    };
    return params.row.status === 'Approved' || 'Rejected' || 'Returned' ?
      (<span>{<Button className="summary-button-review table-button" variant="contained" onClick={onClick} >Review</Button>}</span>) : null
  }

}
```

Comment: How you solve this